# Solving $\mathbf J \times \mathbf B = \mathbf C$, $\mathbf J = \nabla \times \mathbf B$ for $\mathbf J$?

Tags: vector-analysis, physics

Like as is written in the title, I'm trying to solve,

$\mathbf J \times \mathbf B = \mathbf C$

$\mathbf J = \nabla \times \mathbf B$

for $\mathbf J$, in terms of $\mathbf B$ and $\mathbf C$ if possible. The answer can be a differential equation, I just want $\mathbf J$ on one side. I've done some stuff with $\mathbf B$:

$$ (\nabla \times \mathbf B) \times \mathbf B = (\mathbf B \cdot \nabla) \mathbf B -\nabla (B^2/2) =  \mathbf C $$

If I take the curl of this I can get to:

$$ \nabla \times (\mathbf B \cdot \nabla ) \mathbf B  = \nabla \times \mathbf C$$

But I don't know how to deal with the left term... Any help?

Comment: don't you already have $J$ in terms of $B$, $J=\nabla\times B$?

Comment: that is a good point. I'll have to think about that...